# The alert box is displayed too low

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, alerts

I was trying to close a question from https://meta.stackoverflow.com/community/close/626, but the question kept to be shown, even if all seemed to work fine. At the third try, I understood why: There was an alert box being shown.

[image: screenshot]

I could not see it because it was shown on the bottom of the question, after its comments. My screen resolution is 1600x900, but it's not high enough to see the bottom of the question without scrolling.

Comment: Side note: can't the message for that error be any better than that?

Comment: I propose using [this image](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/15e78fafab4bf6f1382005dc78099100?s=256&d=identicon&r=PG), instead of that dialog box. `;)`

Comment: Yeah "only leading in a circle" is pretty terrible copy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the late response, but review has undergone a considerable number of changes since this question was asked, and it appears to be fixed now:

> [image]